# declare subcomponent in module raise compiler error

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am using Dagger 2.24.

I have a subcomponent:

```
@Subcomponent(modules = MyModule.class)
public interface MySubComponent {
    void inject(MyApplication app);
}
```

Since my subcomponent is only used by classes of a specific module, so, I try to declare my subcomponent in that module class by:

```
//Compiler error: An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant
@Module(subcomponents = MySubComponent.class)
abstract class MyModule {
  ...
}
```

When I do above thing, compiler complains "An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant". Why?

Comment: Can you share the content of `MyModule`? BTW you wrote twice `MyModule` but I guess they are two different in the two code blocks right?

Comment: They are referring to the same `MyModule` class.

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular dependency between your module and your subcomponent.

> Since my subcomponent is only used by classes of a specific module [...]

You have to remove `subcomponents = MySubComponent.class` from `MyModule`.

If you want to define some dependencies only for `MySubcomponent`, your main module (which is not `MyModule`) should list `MySubcomponent` in its subcomponent and, as you did correctly, you have to list `MyModule` in the subcomponent's modules. In this way, the dependency of `MyModule` will be provided only to `MySubcomponent`